# Can it require different amounts of energy to generate the same impulse?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, energy, momentum

According to impulse principle the impulse is the same as the change in the object's momentum:
$\bar I = \delta p$

Because the momentum can be calculated like this:
$\bar p = m\bar v$. If we solve speed from that: $\bar v = \frac{\bar p}m$

We can conclude that a certain impulse causes certain change in speed as long as the mass is a constant:
$\delta \bar v = \bar v_2 - \bar v_1 = \frac{\bar p_2}m - \frac{\bar p_1}m = \frac{\bar p_2 - \bar p_1}m = \frac{\delta \bar p}m = \frac{\bar I}m$

However, if we solve how much energy it takes to cause a certain change in speed it depends on the original speed:
$W = \delta E = E_2 - E_1 = \frac 1 2mv_2^2 - \frac 1 2mv_1^2 = \frac 1 2m(v_1 + \delta v)^2 - \frac 1 2mv_1^2 = mv_1\delta v + \frac 1 2m(\delta v)^2$

So my question is: Does the energy needed to generate an impulse of certain magnitude depend on the original speed of the object?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As your calculations show, **yes, it does**.

The reason for this is that the work performed by a force $F$ on an object is proportional to the displacement through which it is applied,
$$W=F \Delta x.$$
If an object is going faster, then for an given time interval $\Delta t$ (and thus a given impulse $I=F\Delta t$) the displacement $\Delta x=v\Delta t$ is bigger, and you must perform more work.